# Simple Snake Game - Snake Head is not moving after ReadKey()

Tags: c#, .net, enums, console-application, console.readkey

The snake head `0` does not move anywhere when `Console.ReadKey()` happens.
Here is the full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SimpleSnakeGame_ConsoleApp
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public bool gameOver = true;
        public int width = 20;
        public int height = 20;

        //HEAD POS
        public int x, y;

        //FRUIT POS
        public int fruitX, fruitY;

        public int score;

        //bir kere basınca oraya gitmeni sağlayacak enum
        enum eDirection { STOP = 0, LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN };
        eDirection dir; //enum class gibi çalışıyor enum'dan dir isimli bir object yarattık

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Program oyun = new Program();

                oyun.Setup();

                oyun.Draw();
                oyun.Input();
                oyun.Logic();


            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        //Setting Up the MAP
        public void Setup()
        {
            gameOver = false;
            string a = "!!!!! SİMPLE SNAKE GAME !!!!!";
            Console.WriteLine(gameOver.ToString() + " " + a, "{0}" + "{1}");
            dir = eDirection.STOP;
            x = width / 2;
            y = height / 2;

            Random rnd = new Random();
            fruitX = rnd.Next(1, 19);
            fruitY = rnd.Next(1, 19);
            score = 0;

        }
        void Draw()
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
                {
                    if (i == y && j == x)
                    {
                        Console.Write("0");
                    }
                    else if (i == fruitY && j == fruitX)
                    {
                        Console.Write("F");
                    }
                    else if (j > 0 && j < height - 1 && i > 0 && i < width - 1)
                    {
                        Console.Write(" ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write("#");
                    }

                }

                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        void Input()
        {
            ConsoleKey key;

            // Key is available - read it
            key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;

            if (key == ConsoleKey.A)
            {
                dir = eDirection.LEFT;
            }
            else if (key == ConsoleKey.D)
            {
                dir = eDirection.RIGHT;
            }
            else if (key == ConsoleKey.W)
            {
                dir = eDirection.UP;
            }
            else if (key == ConsoleKey.S)
            {
                dir = eDirection.DOWN;
            }
            else if (key == ConsoleKey.X)
            {
                gameOver=true;
            }
        }
        void Logic()
        {
            switch (dir)
            {
                case eDirection.LEFT:
                    x--;
                    break;
                case eDirection.RIGHT:
                    x++;
                    break;
                case eDirection.UP:
                    y--;
                    break;
                case eDirection.DOWN:
                    y++;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I guess the problem is `Console.ReadKey()` function here:

```
void Input()
        {
            ConsoleKey key;

            // Key is available - read it
            key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;

            if (key == ConsoleKey.A)
            {
                dir = eDirection.LEFT;
            }
            else if (key == ConsoleKey.D)
            {
                dir = eDirection.RIGHT;
            }
            else if (key == ConsoleKey.W)
            {
                dir = eDirection.UP;
            }
            else if (key == ConsoleKey.S)
            {
                dir = eDirection.DOWN;
            }
            else if (key == ConsoleKey.X)
            {
                gameOver=true;
            }
        }
```

However I do not know what to replace `Console.ReadKey()` with and how to do it.

Here is the OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: Where is your game loop? You need a loop to (a) check input and (b) update the display for each game "tick".

Comment: @MatthewWatson if I put the functions in a while loop of ```while(!oyun.gameOver)``` the game field does not show up in the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct about Console.ReadKey() being the problem as it is blocking and will pause the game until a key is pressed.

You will need to do something like this:

```
if (Console.KeyAvailable)  
{  
    ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey(true);  
    // process key here
}
```

This way you are reading from the console without blocking until a key is pressed.